# Getting data to show up on a page only if it is filled in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a custom checkout/shopping cart system. I'm running into an issue though. Some of my products will have different options like colors or sizes. As of now, I only have one database table created called products with all of my information in it like product name, id, price, item details, description, etc. I display all of the products on one page and then if you click on the products link I grab that ID and show that products information.

Should I add a colors and size option to my products db or create new db tables?

Then how can I get these options to display ONLY if that product has different colors or sizes?

I'm adding products to my cart like this

```
<div class="addcartbox">
    <div class="productitemwrapper">
        Price: <span class="addtocartboxtotal"><?php echo "$" . $products[$product_id]['price']; ?></span>
        <div class="productdetailquantity"><?php echo"<form action='./itemsadded.php?view_product=$product_id' method='POST'>"?>
            <select class="productquantity" name='quantity'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2'>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
                <option value='5'>5</option>
                <option value='6'>6</option>
                <option value='7'>7</option>
                <option value='8'>8</option>
                <option value='9'>9</option>
                <option value='10'>10</option>
            </select>
        </div><br><br>

        //I want to add the color and size options here
        <div class="productdetailaddbutton">
        <?php 
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id' />
            <input type='submit' class='addtocart' name='add_to_cart' value='Add to cart' />";  
        ?>
        <br>
        <?php
            // Add Product to Cart
            if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
                $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

                // If item is already in cart, tell user
                if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$product_id])) {
                    echo "Item already in cart!<br />";
                }
                // Otherwise add to cart
                else {
                    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$product_id]['product_id'] = $_POST['product_id'];
                    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$product_id]['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                    echo $message = "Added to cart!";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the color and size options in the location I commented in my code. I want to echo out the info from the db in option values. So this would mean I would have to have each color or size be a different row in the database table correct?

I'm not going to have many products, so this doesn't need scaled to a huge degree. I just more or less need this to work in the system I have set up, so I can continue displaying my products with a loop I created and only showing these fields if the product has different options with it.

UPDATE:

I based this on how I was displaying all of my products through a foreach loop. I'm not sure if I am even close...

```
<?php
//connection to db
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bfb"); 

//Check for errors  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf ("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Fetch products
    $products = array();
    $colors = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM colors");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($colors)) {
        $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;
    }

// Loop to display all products
    foreach($colors as $id => $color) { ?>
<select name='colors'>
                <option value='1'><?php echo $color; ?></option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I've usually seen color/size options in another table, but since you built this custom you'll have to decide how you want to do it.  The approach many people take is to have a table with the product base sku, the color, the size, and something to append to the sku.  That way, the sku P103 becomes P103REDXL.  Obviously setting all of this up will be different for each business depending on how they manage inventory.  But since you designed this custom, it should be easy to work it in

Comment: @RightClick Great info, thanks! How would I get the option to add a color in my page if that product has those options? Then obviously not show them if they do not have the options. I'm really stuck on that part as well and would really like to automate this as much as possible.

Comment: use a `SELECT` query, where the current product sku is equal to the base skus in your color/size chart and have positive inventory.  If it returns rows, build a dropdown or radio input.  If it doesn't return rows, do nothing.  On the server side, concatenate your base sku and the color/size ending, and that's your full sku.  You could also concatenate them all first so that the input passes the entire sku, then you'd probably have to make fewer changes to your other code. It really depends what you've got so far

Comment: @RightClick Lets say I made a db table called colors. Would I add blue, red, green, etc as different rows. If so how could I associate those colors with the product I need them for? If I added a row for SKU how would that configure that? I'm also still really confused on how to get those colors to show up on the page. I will edit my question to try and show how I am understanding it as of now.

Comment: @RightClick I edited it. I would put into the part I labeled in the code above it....  //I want to add the color and size options here

Comment: To link the colors, you could use a `foreign key` and then make a `SELECT` call in your color db to get all the article that match your product id

Comment: I'm not sure how to do any of what you just said other than a SELECT call.

Comment: go read my first comment. you need another column for the sku in your color table, or if not sku then some identifier.

Comment: If I added the SKU row, how would I configure the products SKU's to the colors I want though. Say I have 20 products, 50 colors and 4 of the products are only using red and blue. How can I get that that product to only pull out red and blue?

Comment: `P103  BLUE  XL  P103BLXL  15`    `P103  RED  XL  P103RDXL  12`   `P103  RED  S  P103RDS  8`   `P105  BLUE  XL  P105BLXL  12`  `parent_sku  color  size  full_sku  qty`  see how there are 2 records with BLUE XL, you'll need to do that for each product where there is a blue xl.  20 products * 5 colors * 3 sizes = 300 skus.  You'll want to be able to remove red xl from just one product, so you'll end up with many rows

Comment: I believe I somewhat understand that. So you are saying the 12 15 or number that proceeds the sku is an id of sort associated with the products? The biggest part I am not understanding is where do I put these SKU's in the db so that it ties all of this together. I understand how to concatenate all of this so that is creates the final SKU. Do I go into the colors table in my db and just type in SKU's in the insert option? Wouldn't that just combine them all??